# jquery - how to get value of php GET variable from address bar

Tags: php, jquery

```
var c = window.location.href;
alert (c);  //  http://localhost/x1/andesignup/index.php?lang=en&cat=balls
var d = c.split('?')[1];
var e = d.split('&')[0];
var f = e.replace("lang=", "");
alert (f);  //  en
```

This works but is there a faster way to get value of `lang`.

Something like

```
var f = lang.value;
```

Comment: You need more jQuery for that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this:

```
$.urlParam = function(name) {
    var results = (new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)")).exec(window.location.href);
    if (results == null) return null;
    else return results[1] || 0;
};

var param = $.urlParam("action");
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25359264/3300831).